# Play Framework 2.2.1 Ebean Many-to-Many Relationship Between 3 Tables

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a case with 2 DB Tables 'Player' and 'Game'. I want to create another table called 'PlayerPlayedWithOpponentGame' which must have the following fields:
- playerA (fk pointing to Player id)
- playerB (fk pointing to Player id)
- gamePlayed (fk pointing to Game id)

I've tried many thing but nothing worked correctly! Any suggestions???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And don't forget to add the code you tried. It will be easier to find out your bug.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to create three entities. (Player, Game, PlayerPlayedWithOpponentGame)

Player <-(ManyToOne)- PlayerPlayedWithOpponentGame(PlayerA)

Player <-(ManyToOne)- PlayerPlayedWithOpponentGame(PlayerB)

Game   <-(ManyToOne)- PlayerPlayedWithOpponentGame(gamePlayed)

I had some issues with unidirectional relations, if you have them to, do it just bidirectional. (so obviously on one side ManyToOne and on the other OneToMany)